# No cierra menú responsive cuando el link es de la misma pagina

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html5

**No cierra el menú responsive cuando el link es de la *MISMA PAGINA*.**

Buenas gente, no logro hacer cerrar **solo** mi nav-btn luego de un click en los links. Queda abierto y tengo que cerrarlo para ver la section en la misma pagina.

¿Alguien sabe como se logra este cambio de estado en el menú?

Gracias.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
<div class="nav-btn">
    <div class="nav-links">
        <ul>
            <li class="nav-link" style="--i: .6s">
                <a href="https://.com/">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-link" style="--i: .85s">
                <a href="">Menu<i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></a>
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="dropdown-link">
                            <a href="#first">cosa</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown-link">
                            <a href="#">cosa</a>
                        </li>
</div>
```

Comment: Buenas, por favor agrega todo el codigo necesario para crear un [mre] por que ahora mismo no puedo replicar tu problema con solo ese codigo

Comment: La solución es sencilla, agrega un evento `click` a todos los enlaces del menú y haz que lo oculte.